# Eclipse - set custom color theme and now when highlighted things turn black

Tags: java, eclipse

So i got a custom color theme in eclipse, decided i didn't like it and went back to the default.  Now you know when you click on a variable in eclipse it highlights all the other mentions of it.  It does it in black.  So i successfully removed the other features just not that.  Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is can be modified under the `Annotations` section of the `Preferences` dialog (as shown below).

[image]